# How do I find a missing side of a triangle with Only 2 given side lengths?

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem

A gas pipeline must be diverted around a swamp as shown below. The pipeline costs $1225/m to install. How much more money would have to be spent to divert the pipeline around the swamp?

Here is an image to help.

[image: Diagram]

Keep in mind, I am only in grade 11 math, please keep things simple.

Comment: With the given information, it cannot be answered.  Best you can do is come up with a range.  0<increased cost<(2.67+3.88) 1225

Comment: There is something wrong with the setup of this problem. With just two sides given, you cannot calculate the third side. It depends on the angle between those two sides. Is anything else possibly given that you may have missed in your post?

Comment: Or, maybe, the problem is just to calculate the cost of building the diversion? (Rather than an additional cost...) Maybe someone mistakenly added that word (“how much **more**”) in the problem setup???

Comment: The final answer is $1555.75, so my teacher has solved it.  I just don't know how he came up with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is claiming that the added distance is $1.27$ km, which means the straight line distance is $5.28$ km.  There is not enough information in the problem to make that claim.  I tried making the angle right, but that doesn't work.  The added distance is larger than that.

Comment: i will ask him at school tomorrow what on earth is going on with this question. I just doesn't makes sense, how i posted it here is exactly how i have it on my test review. With 2 sides and nothing else, i dont think it is possible to solve the triangle.

Comment: But knowing the answer, we can look up the angles of the triangle, and one of them is suspiciously close to 45 degrees. I wonder if that is the missing bit of data.